# How to insert JSON document with key and list of values into oracle db

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a json document/file in this format:

```
{
  "key1": [ "v11", "v12", "v13"],
  "key2": [ "v21", "v22", "v23", "v24"],
  "key3": [ "v31", "v32"],
...
}
```

When I try to insert this into oracle db, it gets the data in the form of 'keys' as column names and list of values as a single row of clobs:

Format 1:

```
key1                   |      key2                    | key 3           | ....
-----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------+--------
["v11", "v12", "v13"]  | ["v21", "v22", "v23", "v24"] | [ "v31", "v32"]
```

Instead I want to load it as:

Format 2:

```
Project Name   |      Values
---------------+------------------
key1           | "v11", "v12", "v13"
key2           | "v21", "v22", ........
....
```

How can I load it in this format or transform the existing data into the second format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Getting the key names with pure SQL is almost impossible, maybe with some Reg_Ex sorcery.
However, if it's ok to use PL/SQL please refer to this document by oracle: [Oracle JSON Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.html)